# Server not found when using 3G/4G

Tags: dns, server, downtime

I have been battling with an error that presents itself to some of my customers for the best part of 3 months.

My hosting provider NameCheap can not fix the error so I am poised to move the site completely.

`https://smilespowder.com` connects using WiFi, however, a number of customers cannot reach the website using 3G/4G and EDGE.

`traceroute` command returns:

> unknown host smilespowder.com

Android returns:

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

iOS returns:

> Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

All of your DNS records look ok

```
dig +nocmd smilespowder.com any +multiline +noall +answer
smilespowder.com.   857 IN A 37.61.237.48
smilespowder.com.   86057 IN NS ns2.creativelaundry.co.uk.
smilespowder.com.   86057 IN NS ns1.creativelaundry.co.uk.
smilespowder.com.   857 IN MX 0 mail.smilespowder.com.
dig +nocmd www.smilespowder.com any +multiline +noall +answer
www.smilespowder.com.   1198 IN CNAME smilespowder.com.
```

and you have a redirect in place to redirect non http to https

```
curl -I http://www.smilespowder.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2016 18:41:44 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: wfvt_3106908635=57644469cc585; expires=Fri, 17-Jun-2016 19:11:45          GMT; path=/; httponly
Location: https://smilespowder.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I throttled my speed to 2G speeds and didn't get any type of error either.

However, I did notice that the Nameservers you have listed are not valid and the root domain `creativelaundry.co.uk` doesn't show the subdomain as created either.

```
dig @8.8.8.8 +nocmd ns1.creativelaundry.co.uk +answer
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23902
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.creativelaundry.co.uk. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
creativelaundry.co.uk.  587 IN  SOA ns41.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net.    2016050400 28800 7200 604800 600

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 17 13:57:40 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

Personally i would set up a cloudflare account, change your nameservers and let cloudflare handle your dns. I would assume your nameservers not resolving has a big part to play in your intermittent troubles.